# Facebook Graph API comments request return empty array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

When I try to get all my "comments" on Facebook Graph API, using the method described here...

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490

using the method below and replacing the {YOUR_URL} with the URL of the page where the facebook comments box lives, like below...

https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={YOUR_URL}

I have an empty array returned...

```
{
  "{YOUR_URL}": {
    "data": [
    ]
  }
}
```

I though this was unusual since the comments box on that page certainly had comments, but were not appearing on the Graph API call.

I tried doing the same using the Graph API Explorer tool, with the same results.

Thinking it might be an issue with the Graph API, I tried to query the comments out with FQL and the PHP API by setting a new Facebook Object and runnign a query as follows.

```
SELECT post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time FROM comment WHERE object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url ='{YOUR_URL}')
```

Once again with the same results, a empty array.

I tried ckecking for likes as well, with the same results, an empty array.

Tried encoding the URL and placing that on both the API call and the FQL request, the same results.

I see that there are facebook comments on the pages, but I am not able to obtain them through the Graph API or a FQL query.

Has anyone else come across this issue and did you find a way to get your comments out. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It normally works.  For example check this link:
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490

What is the url you are using?  Facebook Graph API url's are quite sensitive so make sure you are accessing it in the exact same format (eg same casing, same querystring, trailing slash, etc).  Also, check to see if the plugin on your page is setting a href or data-href attribute pointing it to a different location.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I tried working with the URL's not much luck. You are more than welcome to look at the URL. It is here...

http://www.comsoc.org/blog/message-ieee-communications-society-president-passing-steve-jobs

Appreciate your help.

Comment: @casaswing That url contains disQus comments system not FB comments. I recently designed a FB & DisQus comments scraper software so I'm pretty sure that you mistook it wrongly.